# Eager , Lazy and explicit loading in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-6, lazy-loading

I have read this [tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/entity-framework5-introduction.aspx) and this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) but I don't understand exactly the use of each loading type.

**I Explain**

I have this POCO :

```
public partial class dpc_gestion
{
    public dpc_gestion()
    {
        this.ass_reunion_participant = new HashSet<ass_reunion_participant>();
        this.dpc_participant = new HashSet<dpc_participant>();
        this.dpc_reunion = new HashSet<dpc_reunion>();
    }

    public int dpc_id_pk { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> dpc_id_gdp_fk { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> dpc_id_theme { get; set; }
    public int dpc_id_animateur_fk { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> dpc_date_creation { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> dpc_date_fin { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> dpc_date_engag_anim { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> dpc_flg_let_engag_anim { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> dpc_flg_fsoins_anim { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ass_reunion_participant> ass_reunion_participant { get; set; }
    public virtual theme_dpc theme_dpc { get; set; }
    public virtual gdp_groupe_de_pair gdp_groupe_de_pair { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<dpc_participant> dpc_participant { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<dpc_reunion> dpc_reunion { get; set; }
}
```

I understood this :

1. **For Lazy loading** : because the load is lazy, if I call the dbset `dpc_gestion` all navigation properties **won't** be loaded. This type of loading is the best in performance and responsiveness. It is enabled by default and If I'd like to re-enable it I have to set :

   ```
   context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;    
   context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
   ```
2. **For the eager loading**
   It is not lazy: it loaded all navigation properties when I load `dpc_gestion`. The navigation properties can be loaded using `include` method. To enable this loading type :

   ```
   context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
   ```
3. **For the explicit loading**
   It is like the eager loading but we use `Load` method instead of `include`.

So I'd like to know :

1. If this small resume is true ?
2. If it is true, what is the difference between eager and explicit loading?
3. If I Use **lazy loading** and I call for example `dpc_gestion.dpc_participant`, does the navigation properties loads?or I will get an exception?
4. Is there a case when eager loading or explicit loading were better than lazy loading in performance and responsiveness?

Thanks

Comment: using ModelView is the best practice

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> If this small resume is true ?

Yes.

> If it is true, what is the difference between eager and explicit loading?

**Eager loading** is the opposite of **Lazy loading** but **Explicit loading** is similar to **lazy loading**, **except that:** you explicitly retrieve the related data in code; it doesn't happen automatically when you access a navigation property. You load related data manually by getting the object state manager entry for an entity and calling the `Collection.Load` method for collections or the `Reference.Load` method for properties that hold a single entity.

From [techblog](http://techblog.treenodes.com/index.php/2012/06/26/understanding-lazy-loading-eager-loading-and-explicit-loading-with-entity-framework-implementation/):

> Eager Loading :
>
> Eager loading is the **opposite of** Lazy loading which is : The process
>   of loading a specific set of related objects along with the objects
>   that were explicitly requested in the query.
>
> Explicit Loading :
>
> Explicit loading is defined as : when objects are returned by a query,
>   related objects are not loaded at the same time. By default, they are
>   not loaded until explicitly requested using the Load method on a
>   navigation property.

And:

> If I Use lazy loading and I call for example `dpc_gestion.dpc_participant`, does the navigation properties loads?or I will get an exception?

You don't get any exception and the navigation properties should loads.

> Is there a case when eager loading or explicit loading were better
>   than lazy loading in performance and responsiveness?

**Eager loading** is typically more efficient when you need the related data for all retrieved rows of the primary table. And also when relations are not too much, **eager loading** will be good practice to reduce further queries on server. But when you know that you will not need a property instantly then **lazy loading** maybe a good choice. And also eager loading is a good choice in a situation where your db context would be disposed and lazy loading could not take place anymore. For example consider the following:

```
public List<Auction> GetAuctions()
{
    using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
    {
        return db.Auctions.ToList();
    }
}
```

After calling this method, You cannot load the related entity lazily because the `db` is disposed and so the **Eager Loading** would be a better choice here.

One more thing to note is: **Lazy loading** will produce several SQL request while **Eager loading** load data with one request. **Eager loading** is also a good choice to solve the *n+1 selects issue* in ORMs.
Have a look at this post: [What is the n+1 selects issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue)

Comment: @LamloumiAfif...One more thing to note is: Lazy loading will produce several SQL request while Eager loading load data with one request.

Comment: Also, setting `LazyLoadingEnabled = false` does not enable eager loading. It disables lazy loading. It is possible to eager load using `Include` when lazy loading is enabled

Comment: @Colin Is it true that the only way of eager loading is using Include?

Comment: @AndesLam I would define eager loading as fetching entities up front in the original query - which I think would require `Include`. You can call Load on navigation properties - but I wouldn't call that eager loading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships#loading-related-objects

Comment: @Colin The reason I am confused is because in OP's words, "It is not lazy: it loaded all navigation properties when I load dpc_gestion". It is as if navigation properties are fetched in the first place in eager loading automatically. However, what I have learnt so far doesn't give me that impression--include is the only way and it is a manual process.

Answer (score 11):

**Question 1 and 2:**

Your explanation of **lazy loading** and **eager loading** is correct.
The use of **explicit loading** is a bit different than you described.

`EntityFramework` returns `IQueryable` objects, which essentially contain the query to the database. But these are not executed until the first time they are enumerated.
`Load` executes the query so that its results are stored locally.
Calling `Load` is the same as calling `ToList` and throwing away that `List`, without having the overhead of creating the `List`.

**Question 3:**

If you use lazy loading, `EntityFramework` will take care of loading the **navigation property** for you, so you won't get an exception.
Keep in mind that this can take a while and make you application *unresponsive*.

**Question 4:**

In disconnected cases (e.g. network application) you *can't* use **lazy loading**, because these objects are translated into DTOs and then not tracked by `EntityFramework`.

Also, if you know you're going to use a **navigation property**, its good practice to load it **eagerly**, so you don't have to wait until they are loaded from the database.
For example, lets say you store the result in a list and bind it to a WPF DataGrid. If the DataGrid accesses a property that is not loaded yet, the user experiences a noticeable timeout until that property is displayed. Additionally the application will not respond during the loading time (if you dont load asynchronously).

Comment: Also keep in mind that for lazy loading the context must be alive, otherwise an exception will be thrown. And I would say that in disconnected scenarios you *can* use lazy loading as long as you're building the object graph that's going to be serialized, although it's more common to load everything you need explicitly, either by `Include` or `Load`.