# Explicit Loading ? where it is different from Lazy loading and Eager loading?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm

I am new to entity framework, I read few article regarding different context loading mechanism in Entity framework. by default lazy loading is enabled but If there is a high ping between your web and sql servers you would go with Eager loading instead of loading related items 1-by-1 with lazy Loading.but one thing really confuse me is *Explicit loading* .It's done by disabling lazy loading but it itself not even a Eager loading ..I tried to done something for my research....

```
private static void DifferentLoading()
        {

            //Lazy - by default
            using (var ctx = new NorthwindDBContext())
            {
                var query = ctx.Categories.Take(3);
                foreach (var category in query)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(category.CategoryName);
                    foreach (var product in category.Products)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(product.ProductName);
                    }

                }
            }
            //Eager loading 
            using (var ctx = new NorthwindDBContext())
            {
                ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                var query = ctx.Categories.Include("Products").Take(3); // .Include() to load forcefully 
                foreach (var category in query)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(category.CategoryName);
                    foreach (var product in category.Products)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(product.ProductName);
                    }

                }
            }
            //Explicit loading -- On Demand load
            using (var ctx = new NorthwindDBContext())
            {
                ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                var query = ctx.Categories.Take(3);
                foreach (var category in query)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(category.CategoryName);
                    ctx.Entry(category).Collection(c => c.Products).Load(); // .Include() to load explicitely  
                    foreach (var product in category.Products)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(product.ProductName);
                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

I found different sql fired for different scenarios

1) Lazy

```
SELECT TOP (3) 
    [c].[CategoryID] AS [CategoryID], 
    [c].[CategoryName] AS [CategoryName], 
    [c].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [c].[Picture] AS [Picture]
    FROM [dbo].[Categories] AS [c]
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @EntityKeyValue1 Int = 1
-- EndRegion
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ProductID] AS [ProductID], 
    [Extent1].[ProductName] AS [ProductName], 
    [Extent1].[SupplierID] AS [SupplierID], 
    [Extent1].[CategoryID] AS [CategoryID], 
    [Extent1].[QuantityPerUnit] AS [QuantityPerUnit], 
    [Extent1].[UnitPrice] AS [UnitPrice], 
    [Extent1].[UnitsInStock] AS [UnitsInStock], 
    [Extent1].[UnitsOnOrder] AS [UnitsOnOrder], 
    [Extent1].[ReorderLevel] AS [ReorderLevel], 
    [Extent1].[Discontinued] AS [Discontinued]
    FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[CategoryID] = @EntityKeyValue1
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @EntityKeyValue1 Int = 2
-- EndRegion
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ProductID] AS [ProductID], 
    [Extent1].[ProductName] AS [ProductName], 
    [Extent1].[SupplierID] AS [SupplierID], 
    [Extent1].[CategoryID] AS [CategoryID], 
    [Extent1].[QuantityPerUnit] AS [QuantityPerUnit], 
    [Extent1].[UnitPrice] AS [UnitPrice], 
    [Extent1].[UnitsInStock] AS [UnitsInStock], 
    [Extent1].[UnitsOnOrder] AS [UnitsOnOrder], 
    [Extent1].[ReorderLevel] AS [ReorderLevel], 
    [Extent1].[Discontinued] AS [Discontinued]
    FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[CategoryID] = @EntityKeyValue1
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @EntityKeyValue1 Int = 3
-- EndRegion
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ProductID] AS [ProductID], 
    [Extent1].[ProductName] AS [ProductName], 
    [Extent1].[SupplierID] AS [SupplierID], 
    [Extent1].[CategoryID] AS [CategoryID], 
    [Extent1].[QuantityPerUnit] AS [QuantityPerUnit], 
    [Extent1].[UnitPrice] AS [UnitPrice], 
    [Extent1].[UnitsInStock] AS [UnitsInStock], 
    [Extent1].[UnitsOnOrder] AS [UnitsOnOrder], 
    [Extent1].[ReorderLevel] AS [ReorderLevel], 
    [Extent1].[Discontinued] AS [Discontinued]
    FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[CategoryID] = @EntityKeyValue1
```

2) Eager

```
SELECT 
    [Project1].[CategoryID] AS [CategoryID], 
    [Project1].[CategoryName] AS [CategoryName], 
    [Project1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Project1].[Picture] AS [Picture], 
    [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project1].[ProductID] AS [ProductID], 
    [Project1].[ProductName] AS [ProductName], 
    [Project1].[SupplierID] AS [SupplierID], 
    [Project1].[CategoryID1] AS [CategoryID1], 
    [Project1].[QuantityPerUnit] AS [QuantityPerUnit], 
    [Project1].[UnitPrice] AS [UnitPrice], 
    [Project1].[UnitsInStock] AS [UnitsInStock], 
    [Project1].[UnitsOnOrder] AS [UnitsOnOrder], 
    [Project1].[ReorderLevel] AS [ReorderLevel], 
    [Project1].[Discontinued] AS [Discontinued]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Limit1].[CategoryID] AS [CategoryID], 
        [Limit1].[CategoryName] AS [CategoryName], 
        [Limit1].[Description] AS [Description], 
        [Limit1].[Picture] AS [Picture], 
        [Extent2].[ProductID] AS [ProductID], 
        [Extent2].[ProductName] AS [ProductName], 
        [Extent2].[SupplierID] AS [SupplierID], 
        [Extent2].[CategoryID] AS [CategoryID1], 
        [Extent2].[QuantityPerUnit] AS [QuantityPerUnit], 
        [Extent2].[UnitPrice] AS [UnitPrice], 
        [Extent2].[UnitsInStock] AS [UnitsInStock], 
        [Extent2].[UnitsOnOrder] AS [UnitsOnOrder], 
        [Extent2].[ReorderLevel] AS [ReorderLevel], 
        [Extent2].[Discontinued] AS [Discontinued], 
        CASE WHEN ([Extent2].[ProductID] IS NULL) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE 1 END AS [C1]
        FROM   (SELECT TOP (3) [c].[CategoryID] AS [CategoryID], [c].[CategoryName] AS [CategoryName], [c].[Description] AS [Description], [c].[Picture] AS [Picture]
            FROM [dbo].[Categories] AS [c] ) AS [Limit1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent2] ON [Limit1].[CategoryID] = [Extent2].[CategoryID]
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[CategoryID] ASC, [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

3)Explicit

```
SELECT TOP (3) 
    [c].[CategoryID] AS [CategoryID], 
    [c].[CategoryName] AS [CategoryName], 
    [c].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [c].[Picture] AS [Picture]
    FROM [dbo].[Categories] AS [c]
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @EntityKeyValue1 Int = 1
-- EndRegion
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ProductID] AS [ProductID], 
    [Extent1].[ProductName] AS [ProductName], 
    [Extent1].[SupplierID] AS [SupplierID], 
    [Extent1].[CategoryID] AS [CategoryID], 
    [Extent1].[QuantityPerUnit] AS [QuantityPerUnit], 
    [Extent1].[UnitPrice] AS [UnitPrice], 
    [Extent1].[UnitsInStock] AS [UnitsInStock], 
    [Extent1].[UnitsOnOrder] AS [UnitsOnOrder], 
    [Extent1].[ReorderLevel] AS [ReorderLevel], 
    [Extent1].[Discontinued] AS [Discontinued]
    FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[CategoryID] = @EntityKeyValue1
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @EntityKeyValue1 Int = 2
-- EndRegion
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ProductID] AS [ProductID], 
    [Extent1].[ProductName] AS [ProductName], 
    [Extent1].[SupplierID] AS [SupplierID], 
    [Extent1].[CategoryID] AS [CategoryID], 
    [Extent1].[QuantityPerUnit] AS [QuantityPerUnit], 
    [Extent1].[UnitPrice] AS [UnitPrice], 
    [Extent1].[UnitsInStock] AS [UnitsInStock], 
    [Extent1].[UnitsOnOrder] AS [UnitsOnOrder], 
    [Extent1].[ReorderLevel] AS [ReorderLevel], 
    [Extent1].[Discontinued] AS [Discontinued]
    FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[CategoryID] = @EntityKeyValue1
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @EntityKeyValue1 Int = 3
-- EndRegion
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ProductID] AS [ProductID], 
    [Extent1].[ProductName] AS [ProductName], 
    [Extent1].[SupplierID] AS [SupplierID], 
    [Extent1].[CategoryID] AS [CategoryID], 
    [Extent1].[QuantityPerUnit] AS [QuantityPerUnit], 
    [Extent1].[UnitPrice] AS [UnitPrice], 
    [Extent1].[UnitsInStock] AS [UnitsInStock], 
    [Extent1].[UnitsOnOrder] AS [UnitsOnOrder], 
    [Extent1].[ReorderLevel] AS [ReorderLevel], 
    [Extent1].[Discontinued] AS [Discontinued]
    FROM [dbo].[Products] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[CategoryID] = @EntityKeyValue1
```

I have already go through this thread , It covers my doubt on eager loading and lazy loading. but still a bit confusion on Explicit loading

[Lazy Loading vs Eager Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366236/lazy-loading-vs-eager-loading)

[Eager , Lazy and explicit loading in EF6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627865/eager-lazy-and-explicit-loading-in-ef6)

Above article really help me to clear my concerns

just one doubt ...why I am going to load something explicitly ...I load it explicitly then use it (Explicit)..better I load it when I need it (Lazy)..To this point there is no use of explicit loading..When to use explicit loading over lazy loading ? Any help

Now My questions are ,
1) When to use what ? specially do we really need explicit loading ? if yes , when we need it ?
2) To me query generated for lazy loading and explicit loading are almost similar ? what is the actual difference between lazy and explicit loading ?

Comment: @user3185569 , Thanks for the reference , I am getting a bit confuse for explicit loading ..above article clear my doubt on early and lazy loading

Comment: Sorry i meant this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34627865/eager-lazy-and-explicit-loading-in-ef6

Comment: @user3185569 . It helps , Thanks you ..just one doubt ...why I am going to load something explicitly ...I load it explicitly then use it (Explicit)..better I load it when I need it (Lazy)..To this point there is no use of explicit loading..When to use explicit loading over lazy loading ? Any help

Comment: @S.Akbari , yes it helps . Thanks

Comment: @S.Akbari -- Can you please help me with the answer of comment section regarding explicit loading , I load it explicitly then use it (Explicit)..better I load it when I need it (Lazy)..To this point there is no use of explicit loading..When to use explicit loading over lazy loading ?

Comment: @RahulChowdhury They are not loaded until explicitly requested. When you want to load them explicitly and not automatically use Explicit Loading.  But note as I said they are not loaded until explicitly requested (unlike Eager Loading)