# Must I use "Using" block in Entity Framework 6 for DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

**This is question is not** about the "Using" in general of c#, and not about when/why to use it etc..

The question is, does the DBContext object dispose the connection by itself, and therefore I don't need to use `using` to make it dispose, there is no question about it so **don't mark it as duplicated**

```
using (DBContext db = new DBContext())
{
    var Order =  db.Order.First(r => r.OrderID == 6);
    Order.Type = 6;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Or without using

```
DBContext db = new DBContext();
var Order =  db.Order.First(r => r.OrderID == 6);
Order.Type = 6;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Because I see in [this source](https://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext/) that `using` is not necessary and it's better not to use it.

Will Entity Framework dispose the connection for me?

Comment: One of the impacts of using is when you are dealing with eager loading and lazy loading. Check the last part of this answer for more details https://stackoverflow.com/a/34628138/2946329

Answer (score 2):

The lifetime of the context begins when the instance is created and ends when the instance is either disposed or garbage-collected. Use `using` if you want all the resources that the context controls to be disposed at the end of the block.

When you use `using`, the compiler automatically creates a `try`/`finally` block and calls `Dispose()` in the `finally` block.